# Rails 4: setting request.format does not update params[:format]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

In Rails 3, `params` and `request.parameters` refer to the same object.

With the addition of strong parameters in Rails 4, `params` now refers to a distinct instance of `ActionController::Parameters` that is created from `request.parameters`.

A side effect of this is that once you have called `params` (thereby creating the distinct `Parameters` object), calling `request.format=` will not update `params`.

Rails 3:

```
params # set @_params to request.parameters
request.format = "mobile"
params[:format]
=> "mobile"
```

Rails 4:

```
params # set @_params to Parameters.new(request.parameters)
request.format = "mobile"
params[:format]
=> nil
```

This isn't technically a bug because it's easy enough for client code to look to `request.format` instead of `params[:format]` as the source of truth for this information (and not expect to be able to use both interchangeably).

But it *feels* like a design regression to me. Having `params` and `request.parameters` be the same "except for the exceptions" is causing a bug for us now, and I expect it to cause bugs for many devs in the future.

Am I Doing It Wrong? If so, why isn't this really an issue and what should I be doing differently? Note that the use case that brought me down this path is the exact one from the [docs for format=](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/MimeNegotiation.html#method-i-format-3D).

Answer (score 1):

This is likely the case because the `params` hash is intended to be business data for your application, whereas `request.format` represents the HTTP Request response requests'. So what you do with the contents of `params` would still be the same, but you would have the flexibility to change the request format without changing the business data.

Think of it as separation of concerns.